Haraux's article request
I'm trying to find the article "Haraux, A., Séries lacunaires et contrôle semi-interne des vibrations d'une plaque rectangulaire., J. Math. Pures Appl. (9)68(1989), no.4, 457–465." 
I could find the book of the years of 1836~1945 &  1997~now, but I cannot find the one of 1989. Could you please share a copy of that article with me. Thank you very much!

It's supposed to be available here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?docId=00217824&issue=4&page=457&volume=68 but apparently, "no results found."

the period 1946-1996 has not been digitized (presumably for copyright reasons), see https://cfp.mathdoc.fr/periodique/7076/ ; you will want to consult a library.
